# How Do I get City State Zip in MVC 3 URL Route without writing a controller for every state and actions for each city

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-mapping

I have the need to have the urls in my bosses application look like:

```
http://domain.com/Texas/Dallas/72701
```

However, I don't want to write a controller for every state and an action for every city.

```
routes.MapRoute(
"DrillDown", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{ZipId}", 
new { controller = "State", action = "City", ZipId = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter     defaults
```

Can someone help me write a pattern for the routes that will accept State/City/Zip without destroying the ability for me to have regular routes with controller/Action/Param ?

Looking all over and can't find any direction.

Comment: +1 This is the question I've been looking for the answer to since I started using MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to add one more path segment to the domain path you could get this to work pretty easily

```
routes.MapRoute(
"DrillDown", // Route name
"Location/{State}/{City}/{ZipId}", 
new { controller = "Location",
      action = "DrillDownAction", 
      State= UrlParameter.Optional, 
      City = UrlParameter.Optional,
      ZipId = UrlParameter.Optional
}
```

Which would give you urls in the form: http://www.domain.com/Location/{State}/{City}/{ZipId}

Comment: Instead of Location, we just named it USA.  When we support other countries, it will make since to have a different controller.  Thanks Jason.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by adding a route for each state:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
"TexasDrillDown", // Route name 
"Texas/{City}/{ZipId}",  
new { controller = "DrillDownController", action = "DrillDownAction", ZipId = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

However, if you have fewer other controllers than states, you might prefer to just make your DrillDown the default route and manually map the other controllers like this:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
"Users", // Route name 
"Users/{action}/{id}",  
new { controller = "Users", id= UrlParameter.Optional});

routes.MapRoute( 
"DrillDown", // Route name 
"{State}/{City}/{ZipId}",  
new { controller = "DrillDownController", action = "DrillDownAction", ZipId = UrlParameter.Optional});
```